# OpenGL in my HWND

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, porting

Right now, I'm trying to port a Direct3D renderer from my engine. I'm and OpenGL begginer so i dont have much knowlegde about OpenGL, as now i can create windows and do my render via *glut*, but i can't use glut for my project, because the HWND is created in my code and then sent to the renderer DLL

```
// Where pWindow is already a valid HWND target of the renderer 
//(Currently Direct3D9 and Direct3D10
pRenderer = pCreateGraphics(800, 600, false, pWindow);
```

My question is: *Is there library similar to **GLUT** that has a similar behaviour as GLUT, but allowing my to use my own window handle?*

**Note:** *I prefer using a lib instead of reinventing the wheel, but i will do if there is not a library that can help me*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can have a look at [GLFW's](http://glfw.sourceforge.net/) source code or [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) tutorials and grab the OpenGL init code.

Comment: I'll have a look at GLFW's, about NeHe, i forgot to add that to my post, but I prefer using a lib instead of reinventing the wheel, thanks

Comment: ok, well GLFW doesn't allow you to pass your own HWND in fact, but having your own opengl context init code isn't much code

Comment: Maybe not, but what i try to achieve is gonna be hard tough xD thanks

Answer (score 0):

SDL lets you get the window handle.
I don't know if the used pixel format can be assumed to be DirectX compatible though.